# Элемент для динамического графика

Tags: анимация, wpf

Нужно написать анимацию сердечного ритма. Какой элемент лучше использовать для динамического графика сердечного ритма? Помогите советами, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx), [графические примитивы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) и [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx) для анимации, соответственно.